# Options is not working in Materialize and remove method is also not working when i use jQuery append method

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, materialize

I use materialize css for my project, I have problem when I want to append option in materialize select.

Please have a look at my snippet and make necessary changes to help me out.Thankyou

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".condition").click(function() {
    $('.shw').append($('.hidden').clone().removeClass("hidden"));
  });
});
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".delete").click(function() {
    $('.hidden').remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<div class="hidden">
  <fieldset>
    <table class='addRuleHolder'>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Sensor:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <select>
            <option value="1">S1</option>
            <option value="2">S2</option>
          </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="label-col">
          <label>Threshold Value:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<button  class="waves-effect waves-light btn delete"  >delete</button>
  </fieldset>
</div>


<div style="margin-top: 20px; float:right;padding-right:15px">
  <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn condition"  value="Add">condition</button>
</div>
<br style="clear:both"/>
<div class="shw"></div>
```

Thank you for your help,sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the working script for select

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select').attr("class", "browser-default")
});
```

To delete the div, below is the script

```
   $('.shw').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Good answer, but you could replace the id='delete' by a class='delete' because an id should be a unique identifier : https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Answer (score 0):

You should even remove the div which is appending while deleting or else it won't work.

Comment: Can you be more specific. I didn't get you